# How to encrypt any file no matter what type it is with Python?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

So I tried to read the file and encrypt its content with `cryptography.fernet` but sometimes the file contains characters that can't be encrypted by whatever algorithm is being used in this library. I also tried a library called `pyAesCrypt` which has this function: `pyAesCrypt.encryptFile("data.txt", "data.txt.aes", password)`. But it also can't encrypt some file types like gifs.
I don't know much about the encryption algorithm happening in the background, but is there any way I can encrypt all files no matter what characters they contain? Or maybe encode them first to get rid of these characters then encrypt them? I'm just giving ideas based on the small knowledge I have about this topic.

The code I tried with Fernet library:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

with open(filename, "r") as file:
    file_data = file.read()
    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data.encode()).decode()

with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(encrypted_data)
```

When I try this with GIFs I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 466: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Can you provide code examples of what you have tried, and what types of files didn't work with that approach?

Comment: @bobveringa Okay, I edited the post.

Comment: I edited the post couple times, because of mistakes in the code sample but I tried it without the decode() and encode() methods but also had to do "rb" and "wb" instead of "r" and "b" in the open() function. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must open file in binary mode for reading and writing. since `encrypt` method expect bytes as a parameter, this way you can encrypt any file no matter it's type.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    file_data = file.read()
    encrypted_data = f.encrypt(file_data)

with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(encrypted_data)
```